# My function is not finding my word in the string

Tags: c++, vector

I made a simple program to find words inside of strings and it works well but it can't find the last word in the string. Example: when I type in "Hello world", it will only pushback "Hello".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
vector<char> Buffer2;
string temp;
vector<string> FinalString;
string UserInput;

void SeperateString() {
  for (int x = 0; x < UserInput.size(); x++) {
    temp.clear();
    if (UserInput[x] == ' ') {
      for (int x = 0; x < Buffer2.size(); x++) {
        temp = temp + Buffer2[x];
      }
      FinalString.push_back(temp);
      Buffer2.clear();
    } else {
      Buffer2.push_back(UserInput[x]);
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  getline(cin, UserInput);

  SeperateString();
  for (int x = 0; x < FinalString.size(); x++) {
    cout << FinalString[x] << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: *I made a simple program to find words inside of strings and it works well but...* -- "I built a car and it works well, but I can't make right turns".  Your program is *not* working "well".  BTW, this task is made much simpler by using `std::istringstream` instead of faulty space-checking logic.

Comment: Think about your logic a bit. If you enter `Hello World ` with a space at the end do you get both words? If the loop finishes because the end of the string is reached and `Buffer2` isn't empty should you add the contents to `FinalString`?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be a better implementation for your code:

```
void SeperateString() {

    istringstream ss(UserInput); // needs #include <sstream>
    while (ss >> temp)
    {
        FinalString.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

[`istringstream` documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/),
[`stringstream` documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/).

If you want to stick to your code, at the end of the loop, just check if `Buffer2` has characters or not:

```
for (int x = 0; x < UserInput.size(); x++) {
    temp.clear();
    if (UserInput[x] == ' ') {
        for (int x = 0; x < Buffer2.size(); x++) {
            temp = temp + Buffer2[x];
        }
        FinalString.push_back(temp);
        Buffer2.clear();
    }
    else {
        Buffer2.push_back(UserInput[x]);
    }
}

if (Buffer2.size() > 0)
{
    temp.clear();
    for (int x = 0; x < Buffer2.size(); x++) {
        temp = temp + Buffer2[x];
    }
    FinalString.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the last word separately because it does not have a space after it.

```
void SeperateString() {
for (int x = 0; x <= UserInput.size(); x++) {
    temp.clear();
    if (UserInput[x] == ' ' || x == UserInput.size()) {
        for (int y = 0; y < Buffer2.size(); y++) {
            temp = temp + Buffer2[y];
        }
        FinalString.push_back(temp);
        Buffer2.clear();
    }
    else {
        Buffer2.push_back(UserInput[x]);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the thing I didn't notice and why it didn't work